# Vue Chartjs: How can I update a chart?

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I created a scatter chart with this code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <Scatter ref="myChart" id="my-chart-id" :options="chartOptions" :data="chartData" />
    </div>

    <b-button @click="updateData">Update</b-button>

    {{ chartData.datasets[0].data }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
} from 'chart.js'
import { Scatter } from 'vue-chartjs'

ChartJS.register(LinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, Tooltip, Legend)

export default {
  name: 'ScatterPlot',
  components: { Scatter },
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: {
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Scatter Dataset 1',
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#f87979',
            backgroundColor: '#f87979',
            data: [
              { x: -2, y: 4 },
              { x: -1, y: 1 },
              { x: 0, y: 0 },
              { x: 1, y: 1 },
              { x: 2, y: 4 }
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateData() {
      this.chartData.datasets[0].data = [
        { x: -2, y: 4 },
        { x: -1, y: 1 },
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 1, y: 1 },
        { x: 2, y: 4 }
      ]
      this.$refs.myChart.update();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

When I now press the update button, it updates the data (note that y=40 in the first tuple), but not the chart. Instead, I get this error I don't understand:

[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?
Thanks!

Some thoughts:

- `update()` seems to be the correct function: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html
- The vue chartjs docs don't really help me: https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts

---

EDIT:
Thanks to yoduh's comment, I went one step further!
With this code, I can update the chart:

```
updateData() {
  this.chartData = {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Scatter Dataset 1',
        fill: false,
        borderColor: '#f87979',
        backgroundColor: '#f87979',
        data: [
          { x: -2, y: 40 },
          { x: -1, y: 1 },
          { x: 0, y: 0 },
          { x: 1, y: 1 },
          { x: 2, y: 4 }
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

However, this code **doesn't** work:

```
updateData() {
  let newChartData = this.chartData;
  newChartData.datasets[0].data = [
    { x: -2, y: 40 },
    { x: -1, y: 1 },
    { x: 0, y: 0 },
    { x: 1, y: 1 },
    { x: 2, y: 4 }
  ]
  this.chartData = newChartData
}
```

I cannot see why the second one would not work when the first one does. If I can get the second code working, something like this will also work - and this is where I want to get:

```
let newChartData = this.chartData;
newChartData.datasets[0].data = newChartData.datasets[0].data.filter(value => value.x >= 0)
this.chartData = newChartData
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you need the update() function since the change should be reactive although according to the docs I believe it should be `this.$refs.myChart.chart.update()`.  Try instead replacing the full `chartData` object instead of `chartData.datasets[0].data`

Comment: Replacing the full `chartData` object works - `this.$refs.myChart.chart.update()` is not even needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: However, this is not true all of the time. See edit in question.